# Identify This Glowing Insect

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

When I was walking in my garden at night I saw this small glowing insect, can you identify what is this insect?

Location: **Middle-East Palestine**

Size: **Length about 1 CM**

This image in the dark (see the light of the insect)

[image]

These images taken by flash.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide your location and the approximate size of the insect. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for guidelines for writing *well-received* [tag:species-identification] questions. Thanks

Comment: I voted down because we have clear species ID guidelines, and without them your question can, at best, attract guesses. ID questions lacking details lead to answers without details and we end up with a bunch of internet noise. We're trying to be more accurate than sites like Yahoo Answers or Quora where Q and A quality is minimal. Downvoting is my way of enticing users to put in the little bit of extra effort (which will lead you to getting a more accurate ID). Thanks! :)

Comment: @theforestecologist np I edited my question bro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Appears to be a **[larviform female](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larviform_female) firefly** (order [Coleoptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle); family [Lampiridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly)).

I cannot find a good source for listing/IDing Palestinian fireflies, so I unfortunately cannot give you a definitive answer. I do want to provide some of an answer and an example specimen to get you going on the path of accurately IDing your specimen.

To get you started, your specimen appears similar to *Photinus bromleyi* (seen [here](https://studylib.net/doc/5408428/pests--plagues-and-politics)) and below:

[image]

*Photinus* are a group of North American fireflies, so not likely your species.
According to [firefly.org](https://www.firefly.org/types-of-fireflies.html), the subfamily Luciolinae is found throughout Eurasia, while the genus *Lampyris* is a "[wastebin taxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wastebasket_taxon)" used as a "catch all" for misfit fireflies that is found throughout the world. So I'd start looking in those groups.

I'll dig around for a more Palestinian-oriented bug guide. Again, this is not meant to be an exact answer but just a starting point for you or another user who might have access to Palestinian resources. I'll update if I find something definitive.